"Runtime error: Reshape dimension issue in model definition"
I am working on creating a model definition. The model takes a sequence of images,a sequence of detected object's bounding boxes and associated classes. 
I am using mobilenetv2 as a feature extractor and flattening the bounding box input and classes input. Concatenating all the 3 outputs and  reshaping the output data and passing it through a lstm layer. 
from keras_tuner import HyperModel
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Flatten, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2
import tensorflow as tf

class xyHyperModel(HyperModel):
    def __init__(self, input_shape, batch_size):
        self.input_shape = input_shape
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def build(self, hp):
        # Define input layers with batch size
        inputs = {
            'image_path': Input(shape=(self.input_shape[0], 224, 224, 3), name='image_data', batch_size=self.batch_size),
            'bboxes': Input(shape=(self.input_shape[0], 20, 4), name='bboxes', batch_size=self.batch_size),
            'classes': Input(shape=(self.input_shape[0], 20, 8), name='classes', batch_size=self.batch_size)
        }

        # Image processing using MobileNetV2
        base_model = MobileNetV2(include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
        base_model.trainable = False  # Freeze the MobileNetV2 layers

        # Process each image in the sequence
        image_features = []
        for i in range(self.input_shape[0]):
            img = inputs['image_path'][:, i, ...]  # Extract one image from the sequence
            img_features = base_model(img)
            img_features = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(img_features)
            image_features.append(img_features)

            # Debug print for each image feature
            print(f"Shape of img_features at step {i}: {img_features.shape}")

        # Concatenate image features along the sequence length axis
        x = Concatenate(axis=1)(image_features)
        print("Shape after concatenating image features:", x.shape)

        # Flatten bounding boxes and classes
        bboxes_flat = Flatten()(inputs['bboxes'])
        print("Shape of bboxes_flat:", bboxes_flat.shape)
        classes_flat = Flatten()(inputs['classes'])
        print("Shape of classes_flat:", classes_flat.shape)

        # Concatenate all features
        combined = Concatenate(axis=-1)([x,bboxes_flat, classes_flat])
        print("Shape after concatenation:", combined.shape)

        # Reshape combined features to be suitable for LSTM
        lstm_input = layers.Reshape((self.input_shape[0], -1))(combined)
        print("Shape after reshaping for LSTM:", lstm_input.shape)
        
        # Ensure that only one dimension is -1 for Reshape layer
        lstm_input = layers.Reshape((self.input_shape[0], -1))(lstm_input)  # Adjust this line if necessary
        print("Shape after reshaping for LSTM:", lstm_input.shape)
        
        # LSTM layer
        lstm_units = hp.Int('lstm_units', min_value=32, max_value=128, step=32)
        lstm_out = LSTM(lstm_units, return_sequences=True)(lstm_input)
        print("Shape after LSTM:", lstm_out.shape)

        # Output layers for x and y
        x_output = Dense(20, activation='linear', name='x')(lstm_out)
        print("Shape of x_output:", x_output.shape)
        y_output = Dense(20, activation='linear', name='y')(lstm_out)
        print("Shape of y_output:", y_output.shape)

        # Model definition
        model = Model(inputs=[inputs['image_path'], inputs['bboxes'], inputs['classes']], outputs=[x_output, y_output])

        # Compile the model
        model.compile(optimizer=Adam(hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])),
                      loss={'x': 'mse', 'y': 'mse'},
                      metrics={'x': 'mae', 'y': 'mae'})
        
        return model

# Define input shape (sequence length, height, width, channels)
input_shape = (3, 224, 224, 3)
batch_size = 3  # Adjust according to your needs
hypermodel = xyHyperModel(input_shape, batch_size)

I am getting this runtime error:
Only one input size may be -1, not both 0 and 1   [[{{node functional_1_1/flatten_1_2/Reshape}}]] [Op:__inference_one_step_on_iterator_56973]-
I tried to reshape the output of the concatenation layer so that shape of the data would be compatible with LSTM layer. When I start the tuning of the model using keras tuner's randomsearch I get the output of the print statements and the error.
Shape of img_features at step 1: (3, 1280)
Shape of img_features at step 2: (3, 1280)
Shape after concatenating image features: (3, 3840)
Shape of bboxes_flat: (3, 240)
Shape of classes_flat: (3, 480)
Shape after concatenation: (3, 4560)
Shape after reshaping for LSTM: (3, 3, 1520)
Shape after reshaping for LSTM: (3, 3, 1520)
Shape after LSTM: (3, 3, 64)
Shape of x_output: (3, 3, 20)
Shape of y_output: (3, 3, 20)```


The error you're encountering, "Only one input size may be -1, not both 0 and 1," usually happens when there are conflicting dimensions during reshaping. In your case, the issue seems to be related to the reshaping operations before feeding the data into the LSTM layer.Each image is processed by MobileNetV2, and you get a feature vector of shape (batch_size, 1280) after GlobalAveragePooling2D.Bounding boxes and classes are flattened. They will have shapes (batch_size, sequence_length * num_bboxes * bbox_dim) and (batch_size, sequence_length * num_bboxes * num_classes), respectively.
